# Cannot read length - string array within interface

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I'm having an reading problem with one string array placed inside one interface.

Basically, I'm receiving one string array within one interface with multiple lines, like:

```
{
  "origem": "SERVIDOR",
  "codigoGrupo": "UC",
  "descricaoGrupo": "UC",
  "chave": [
    "UC",
    "AUTOLEITURA",
    "AUTOLEITURA_NAO_UTILIZADA_PROBLEMA_COM_DATA"
  ],
  "valor": "Autoleitura gravada mas não utilizada para faturamento devido a problemas de data."
},
{
  "origem": "SERVIDOR",
  "codigoGrupo": "UC",
  "descricaoGrupo": "UC",
  "chave": [
    "UC",
    "SERVICO",
    "PEDIDO_LIGACAO",
    "CALCULO_CARGA_CORRIGIDA",
    "LISTA_APARELHO_NAO_INFORMADA"
  ],
  "valor": "Lista de aparelhos não informada para o Cálculo da Carga Corrigida."
}
```

I need to filter the values from 'chave' by his length.

Already tried filter using loops like for, forEach, etc.

```
let arrayFiltrada: Array<string> = new Array<string>();
for (let i = 0; i < listaGrupo.length; i++) {
  if (listaGrupo[i].chave.length === 3) {
    listaGrupo.forEach(x => {
      if (!arrayFiltrada.includes(x.chave[1])) {
        arrayFiltrada.push(x.chave[1]);
      }
    });
  } else if (listaGrupo[i].chave.length === 4) {
    listaGrupo.forEach(x => {
      if (!arrayFiltrada.includes(x.chave[2])) {
        arrayFiltrada.push(x.chave[2]);
      }
    });
  } else if (listaGrupo[i].chave.length === 5) {
    listaGrupo.forEach(x => {
      if (!arrayFiltrada.includes(x.chave[3])) {
        arrayFiltrada.push(x.chave[3]);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

The output that I'm expecting, using the two examples above, is something like this:

- When `listaGrupo[i].chave.length === 3` => `"AUTOLEITURA"`;
- When `listaGrupo[i].chave.length === 4` => `"PEDIDO_LIGACAO"`;

Can you give some tips for this problem?

Comment: Is the `listaGrupo` variable an Array in the first place? Since it has a `{},{}` structure in your example and not `[],[]`

Comment: listaGrupo is the interface that contains the string array named 'chave'. In the example that i used, the apresentation of the data is in JSON

Comment: you need filter from key and pass to distinct arrays or sort putting one key on the begin and more keys at last ?

Comment: I need to filter and pass to distinct arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let arrayFiltrada: string[] = listaGrupo.map(x=> x.chave[x.chave.length-2])
```

should help, if I understand your problem correctly.

This will give you a string Array/List with the strings from the penultimate index of your `chave` arrays from every object in the `listaGrupo`.

To only get unique strings you can use one of the following.

```
arrayFiltrada = [...Set(arrayFiltrada)]
```

will create a Set from the Array. Sets don't have duplicate entries. The contents of the Set are then "spread" back into an Array.

```
arrayFiltrada = arrayFiltrada.filter((value,index) => arrayFiltrada.indexOf(value)===i)
```

will filter out values, that can also be found at an earlier point in the array.

From: [Remove Duplicates from an Array](https://wsvincent.com/javascript-remove-duplicates-array/)

Comment: Works fine. I'll need to remove the duplicates but it resolved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
arrayFiltrada: string[] = listaGrupo.sort((a,b) => a.chave.length - b.chave.length);
```

This line will sort itens based in lenght of his "chave" fields, from minor to bigger.